# Core Data Predicate - Check if any element in array matches any element in another array

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to use a predicate to filter objects where an intersection exists between two arrays.

The NSManagedObject has an array(Of Strings) attribute named "transmissions". And there is another array(Of Strings) that will contain words to filter by, named "filters".

I'm not sure how to find if any elements in "transmissions" match any element in "filters".

I've tried

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.transmission in[c] %@",transmissions];
```

or

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY transmission in[c] %@",transmissions];
```

However, core data fetches no results where there should be some.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? For example, are you calling these values from an `NSFetchedResultsController` or an `NSFetchRequest`? I ask because to provide a suitable response, I would need to better understand the code context (not `NSManagedObjectContext`) of your fetch problem.

Comment: My apologies. It is from a regular NSFetchRequest.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *transmission in transmissions) {
    [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"transmission == %@", transmission]];
}
if (predicates.count > 0)
    predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];

// make fetch request using 'predicate'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword `CONTAINS` to check an object exists in a collection.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"favouriteFilms CONTAINS %@", film]
```

I believe the same thing can be achieved with `IN` by switching the LHS and RHS of the predicate. I have only successfully implemented this functionality using `CONTAINS` however.